# logger debug python how to implement in to existing code. Suggestions :)

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, logging

Im trying to add some logging to this so that if a wrong choice of config, etc is chosen it logs this.

Was thinking of adding something like:

```
LOG_FILENAME = 'backup.log'
rotating_handler = RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME,
                    maxBytes=10000000,
                    backupCount=3)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
rotating_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

Not Sure how to add this in to my def read_config.... Can anyone advise further?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import argparse
import shutil
import logging


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Copy multiple Files from a specified data file')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--configfile', default="config.dat", help='file to read the config from')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--location', default="/home/admin/Documents/backup/",help='Choose location to store files')


def read_config(data):
    try:
        dest = '/home/admin/Documents/backup/'
        # Read in date from config.dat
        logger.debug(data = open(data))
        # Interate through list of files '\n'
        filelist = data.read().split('\n')
        # Copy through interated list and strip white spaces and empty lines
        for file in filelist:
            if file:
                shutil.copy(file.strip(), dest)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logger.error("Config file not found")



args = vars(parser.parse_args())
read = read_config(args['configfile'])
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: The question is: "where would it be best to place my logging related code"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figured this out and thought I would post this in case:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import argparse
import shutil
import logging
import re
import pickle
import sys
import subprocess
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Copy multiple Files from a specified data file')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--configfile', default="config.dat", help='file to read the config from')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--location', default="/home/admin/Documents/backup/",help='Choose location to store files')

LOG_FILENAME = 'test.log'
rotating_handler = RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME,
                    maxBytes=10000000,
                    backupCount=3)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
rotating_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(rotating_handler)

def read_config(data):
    try:
        dest = '/home/admin/Documents/backup/'
        # Read in date from config.dat
        data = open(data)
        # Interate through list of files '\n'
        filelist = data.read().split('\n')
        # Copy through interated list and strip white spaces and empty lines
        for file in filelist:
            if file:
                shutil.copy(file.strip(), dest)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logger.error("Config file not found")
        print ("Config File not found")

args = vars(parser.parse_args())
read = read_config(args['configfile'])
```